# How to Style <input type="file"/>

Tags: html, css, user-interface, tailwind-css

Guys I'm making a side project and for that I needed a file selector to upload images to my backend.
But the default one is way too basic and consumes a lot of space.

I want something like this

[image]

But Instead I have this:
[image]

I found some articles about styling this with label but that article was from 2018.

Is there a way to make my file picker to be small and concise, make a little modern?

Thank you.

I tried googling for the style but couldn't find any.
I found an article but it was really old, so I thought it would be best to go to stackOverflow.